# Get clan with bigger kills/deaths coef

Tags: mysql, sql

I got table:

```
id | nick | clanid | kills | deaths | map
 1 | xdd  |      2 |   123 |     23 | 'map_1'
 2 | xd   |      1 |    23 |     32 | 'map_1'
```

this table continuing with similar records. I need to get only 1 result, it's should be clanid and coef(kills/deaths), of course i need the clan with higher coef. This table got many records with players which have different clanids, kills, deaths and map.

The complete result i need: it's clanid with higher coef at current map.
I tried SQL like that:

```
SELECT `clanid`, SUM(kills)/SUM(deaths) as 'coef'
FROM `test_user_stats`
WHERE `map`='map_1'
```

But that returs only 1 record with last clanid and his coef.

What i have to do next?(i obviously need to use LIMIT 1 and ORDER BY `coef`, but i got problems even without going so far).

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: add group by clanid

Comment: You might also want to handle the (probably extremely rare) cases where someone has no deaths?  If you don't then you will start getting division by zero errors...

Comment: Note that SUM(kills)/SUM(deaths)  is not the same as SUM(kills/deaths). Just be sure that you've got the right one.

Comment: MySQL is a bit of a pain in the butt on this...in any other database, your query would return a meaningful error (clanid not in group by).  Anytime you have columns selected then an aggregate, you must group by those columns selected.  In this case, MySQL does the wrong thing (basically returns a random clanid with results) instead of raising an error.  Be careful on other queries like this you may have written, just because MySQL will run it doesn't mean its returning correct results.

Comment: @Twelfth MySQL hasn't behaved that way for quite a while by now. Maybe time to upgrade?

Comment: @Strawberry - the code in this example is behaving that way.  Only recent updates of mysql behave better and it seems more oft than not people are on the older versions.

Comment: @Strawberry - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49496553/where-clause-gives-different-result-wether-in-subquery-or-not    ;)