# WHERE clause gives different result wether in subquery or not

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

Focusing on the two last lines...

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT d.*
   FROM downloads AS d
   LEFT JOIN ps_customer AS pc ON d.id_customer=pc.id_customer
   WHERE pc.active=1
     AND d.id_customer IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY id_product,
            id_customer) AS tmp
WHERE YEAR(tmp.date_download)=2015
  AND tmp.name='Antescofo'
```

and (moved inside the subquery)

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT d.*
   FROM downloads AS d
   LEFT JOIN ps_customer AS pc ON d.id_customer=pc.id_customer
   WHERE pc.active=1
     AND d.id_customer IS NOT NULL
     AND YEAR(d.date_download)=2015
     AND d.name='Antescofo'
   GROUP BY id_product,
            id_customer) AS tmp
```

... gives a different rows count result.

I'm trying to understand why, because a WHERE clause is somehow acting as a filter.

**What difference does it make to filter in the subquery or after?**

In my understanding, the first one goes like *"Select all the deduped downloads from existing and active customers, and show only the downloads of Antescofo product made in 2015"*

And the second one like *"Select all deduped downloads from existing and active customers that concern Antescofo product and made in 2015, and show everything"*.

Comment: Question: Why bother with a sub-query in either case? Seems you are adding complexity with no benefit. If the rows included in a group by have different values for the date_download column, the value in the grouped row will vary, and may not be what you expect.

Comment: To add to what @SloanThrasher said, your use of **LEFT** JOIN is also a bit pointless, the `WHERE pc.active = 1` turns it into an INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you refer to a column that is not in the `group by` list, MySQL will return a randomly chosen value from one of the rows in the group.  So it matters whether you filter inside the subquery, before the `group by`, or outside the subquery, after the `group by`.  In the 2nd case, groups with matching and non-matching rows will be included or excluded randomly.

Answer (score 0):

When you move a where clause like that, you're filtering different things. In the first query, you are filtering grouped results; in the second you are grouping filtered results. On top of all that, in the first one, you are filtering on a non-grouped, non-aggregated field; many flavors of SQL, and MySQL's current default configurations, won't even allow such a (sub)query. That first query is basically filtering on the value of a random selection from the values for each `id_product, id_customer` combination grouped on.